# How to list the web element and how to click the particular link in a web page if we don't have id for that particular link in a web page?

Tags: java, selendroid

I have tried with some coding.But ,I don't know how to render the web element and how to make the click event.

```
List<WebElement> element=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(""));
//for loop
   el.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be tricky most of the time.

I would rather to trigger click or any function in my pages via a javascript command from my java program:

Here is a little example:

```
public void loadCommand(final String cmd) {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            engine.executeScript(cmd);
        }
    });
}
```

I would like to see if there is better option :)